# User Account Registration and Login Based on External API in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-7

I have been trying to create an authentication in Laravel that is based on simple verification via an external services API key. The external API will provide me details like the username associated with the account a user should only have to supply an API key to login. No password, email, or username required.

Looking at Laravel's documentation it seems like using something like they demonstrate in the "[Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)" section may be most applicable. My problem is that this still appears to be based on a email + password credential model.

What is the proper way to modify/extend the frameworks authentication system to use an API key. If I use this manual authentication model I would be able to connect to the API and verify the user but I don't know the best way to modify it to accept an API key and username as the "credentials" for a new account (username would be coming from the API response data).

Comment: Implement a custom Auth guard. See - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: @levi I am a bit confused on what exactly would be required. I see they are using the Java Web Token (JWT) driver here. Would I be needing to create my own driver along with this? I see that it is returning a new instance of `JwtGuard` as well with it. Or is that stuff I would leave there and I would only need to handle creating my own provider? Their example just doesn't really provide much for me to go by when I am at a more beginner level with the framework.

Comment: `jwt` is just an example. See here for thorough example - https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/laravel-api-authenticate-user-with-custom-driver-different-table-using-auth-middleware-fa2cabec2d61

Comment: With a custom guard, you define how user is authenticated.

Comment: @levi thank you, this looks much more helpful than the the often brief Laravel docs :).